# How do I run postman's newman in CI environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, postman, newman

I'd like to run `newman` on my CI environment (solano-ci).

`newman` is a tool that runs through requests in your postman collection.

I have a `newman` script in my `package.json`, and I also have a `npm start` script that starts the server at `localhost:3000`.

`newman` is already configured with environment variables to test endpoints on port `localhost:3000`.

The issue is I need one script that starts the server (`npm start`) and then runs `npm run newman`. But there's a delay between when the server is available and when `newman` runs it's tests. If `newman` runs before the server is available it results in an error for each test.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Right now here's what I tried using [`run-p`](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/master/docs/run-p.md) which works at starting two processes in parallel. Then I have to use `sleep` and set an arbitrary number of time the wait to ensure that the server is ready.

```
"newman": "newman -c ./postman/api.postman_collection.json -e ./postman/local.postman_environment.json",
"newman-sleep": "sleep 10 && npm run newman",
"newman-server": "run-p start newman-sleep"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on) package.

```
npm install --save-dev wait-on
```

Then,

```
"newman-sleep": "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && npm run newman"
```