# Generate Sonar code coverage report from Postman tests

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage, postman, newman

Does anyone know if it is possible(and how) to generate code coverage out of the Postman integration tests execution?

We have integration tests based on Postman and we execute them on Jenkins via a Windows shell command. 
What is quite frustrating, that we don't know how to generate code coverage report and publish it into SonarQube.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can run the tests in the localhost environment and this way coverage will be measured as usual. Actually this is a good CI practice since you'll be testing the code you're trying to deploy rather than a previously published version.

To implement the solution you should point the tests URL to localhost (it's a good idea to indicate the host using a environment variable in order to easily switch between local or production environments) and then add pre and post executions in the jenkins project in order to start the local server before execution and stop it afterwards.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466757/how-do-i-run-postmans-newman-in-ci-environment) shows how to implement the solution on node, and this other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258421/how-to-stop-app-that-node-js-express-npm-start) shows how to stop the local server after execution)

Comment: Well, that's rather arguable whether the developer must run this type of tests  on commit since it might at some point take you 15-30 minutes just at that stage. Anyway, thanks for your solution, but in my case it wasn't applicable since the it's JBoss/Wildfly application server, which I missed to specify.

Comment: the question was not how to automate the execution of the postman tests

Answer (score 0):

At present, no such functionality is provided within Newman, as mapping test coverage via an external command is not standardised across various stacks. Making something like this available (and usable) would also involve creating and providing a manifest of all application URL endpoints to Newman (and altering Newman to interpret it as well), so that there is a global namespace to check percentage coverage against.

Please see https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/408 for more details.

Comment: In fact, after a bit of googling, as a work-around we could use remote Jacoco agent hooked in the java application server. We'll try to run jacoco maven goals before and after the tests execution in order to generate jacoco coverage report. See: [link](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) I'll update the post if we have some progress.

Comment: @GKGeorgiev was you able to that with JaCoCo?

Comment: @Pooja, unfortunately, as many other things, it remained deep inside the backlog and I didn't have the time to try it. Sorry

Comment: @GKGeorgiev after half an year... have you managed to do it?

I am now in the same situration and maybe you already did it. 
I opened a bounty on a similar question, it's yours if you did it already :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869204/how-to-get-code-coverage-using-postman-test

Comment: Dear @aurelius, unfortunately I haven't tried it since I've changed my job in the meanwhile. I still believe it is feasible, but haven't tested. Good luck and please update the thread if you try it out!